# How to mock interface with TRequest

Tags: c#, moq

How can I mock this two interface that I have using Moq?

```
TRequest CreateRequest<TRequest>() where TRequest : IBaseKlaviyoRequest, new();

Task<IKlaviyoResponse<TResponse>> ExecuteAsync<TResponse>(IKlaviyoRequest<TResponse> request);
```

What I tried so far is play around with `It.IsAnyType<IBaseKlaviyoRequest>` or `It.IsSubType<IBaseKlaviyoRequest>` but all of it has errors

```
Setup(mock => mock.CreateRequest<It.IsAnyType<IBaseKlaviyoRequest>()>())
    .Returns(true);
```

Comment: Should it be `Setup(mock => mock.CreateRequest<IBaseKlaviyoRequest>())
    .Returns(<<Object of IBaseKlaviyoRequest>>);` ?

Comment: @user1672994 error: `'IBaseKlaviyoRequest' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'TRequest' in the generic type or method 'IKlaviyoService.CreateRequest<TRequest>()'`

Comment: Create a concrete type that inherits `IBaseKlaviyoRequest` in your tests and use it as a substitute for your actual class. The constraint `new()` specifies that the type argument must have a public parameterless contructor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the key point is `TRequest` MUST have a public parameterless constructor. And IBaseKlaviyoRequest is an interface without a public parameterless constructor constraint. For this reason, if the Setup is

```
Setup(_ => _.CreateRequest<IBaseKlaviyoRequest>())
```

you will get an error message like: `'IBaseKlaviyoRequest' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor`

I think you can base on [It.Subtype](https://github.com/moq/moq4/blob/b7b07279c45c29a201399a7fa93764892422e687/src/Moq/It.cs#L387-L394) to write your type matcher like this:

```
[TypeMatcher]
public sealed class IBaseKlaviyoRequestMatcher<T> 
    : IBaseKlaviyoRequest, ITypeMatcher
{
    // DON'T REMOVE THIS CONSTRUCTOR
    public IBaseKlaviyoRequestMatcher()
    {
    }

    public bool Matches(Type typeArgument)
        => typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(typeArgument);
}

[Test]
public void Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<YourClass>();
    mock
        .Setup(_ => _.CreateRequest<IBaseKlaviyoRequestMatcher<IKlaviyoRequest>>())
        .Returns(() => null!);
}

interface IKlaviyoRequest : IBaseKlaviyoRequest
{
}
```

Comment: the IBaseKlaviyoRequest has some methods in it. What do I gonna do with those as I need to implement it?

Comment: do you have an example? It depends on you. If the method without affecting your test, you can just ignore that.

Comment: The IBaseKlaviyoRequest was from a library, so I am not sure what's inside it.

Comment: ([REF](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#customizing-mock-behavior)): `default behavior is "Loose" mock, which never throws and returns default values or empty arrays, enumerables, etc` 

Accordingly, if the method without affecting your test, you can ignore that.